# Setting a particular date using Jquery

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

I am using mobiscroll.js and am trying to set a particular date like 14/06/2005. This is my senior's code. I am not sure how to edit to set a particular date.

Code:

```
(function ($) {
    var date = new Date();
    $("#id_childbirthday").scroller({mode: 'clickpick',
        dateOrder: 'ddMyyyy',
        dateFormat: 'dd M yyyy',
        endYear: date.getFullYear() - 7,
        startYear: 1990});
})(jQuery);
```

The image looks like this:[image]

I can set the year to the year i want...  But how to edit this code to get it outputting a particular date... Need some guidance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/mobiscroll-core), your mobiscroll instance has a `setValue` method.

The syntax appears to be:

```
$('#id_childbirthday').scroller('setValue', data, true);
```

... where `data` is an array of values, matching the order of the wheels.

Comment: I believe that is the best way to go. Odd to have a `startYear` option, but no `startMonth`, `startDay` etc.

Comment: so if i want to change it to 14/6/2004: $("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', 14/06/2004, true); something like this?

Comment: or $("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', 14/June/2004, true);?

Comment: For `setValue`, possibly `$('#id_childbirthday').scroller('setValue`, [14, 'June', 2004], true)`, depending on how the month wheel is populated. For `setDate` it's `$('#id_childbirthday').scroller('setDate', new Date(2004, 5, 14), true)`. Note the `5`, as month is defined by a 0-based collection in JavaScript dates.

Comment: so basically $('#id_childbirthday').scroller('setDate', new Date(2004, 5, 14), true) means that it refers to 14/6/2004?

Answer (score 3):

I read the document.

I found this:
[doc](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/datetime-preset)

$("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', date, true)

Code shoud be:

```
(function ($) {
    var date = new Date(); //you can specify the date here!
    $("#id_childbirthday").scroller({mode: 'clickpick',
        dateOrder: 'ddMyyyy',
        dateFormat: 'dd M yyyy',
        endYear: date.getFullYear() - 7,
        startYear: 1990});
    var date1 = new Date(2012, 3, 10);
    $("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', date1, true);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: so if i want to change it to 14/6/2004: $("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', 14/06/2004, true); something like this?

Comment: if i do not want the date to be updated, i have to put the "fill" parameter as false right? just verfiying?

Comment: $("#id_childbirthday").scroller('setDate', date1, false);

Comment: but the date is appearing in the box automatically? I would only like to show it only in the mobiscroll...

Answer (score 2):

From [DateTime Preset documentation](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/datetime-preset)

> .scroller('setDate', date, fill, time)     If a preset is selected sets
>   the scroller date/time from the date parameter passed as a Date
>   object. If the 'fill' parameter is true, the associated input field is
>   also updated with the new value. The 'time' parameter specifies the
>   duration of the animation in seconds to scroll the wheels to the new
>   date. There is no animation, if 'time' is not specified

You'd need something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var date = new Date();
    $("#id_childbirthday").scroller({mode: 'clickpick',
        dateOrder: 'ddMyyyy',
        dateFormat: 'dd M yyyy',
        endYear: date.getFullYear() - 7,
        startYear: 1990}).scroller('setDate',new Date(2005,5,14));
})(jQuery);
```